# URL recognize string after ' / ' as parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

Just wondering how to get

```
www.domain.com/home/?welcome
```

as

```
www.domain.com/home/welcome
```

and redirect all traffic to the index file of

```
www.domain.com/home/
```

Thanks.

Comment: URL rewriting and redirecting in the settings of your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

This simple [Trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/) uses a simple solution made of javascript to split a url. First the URL is retrieved, next it is split be the delimiter "/", and each value is stored in an array at a specific index. How you want to manipulate you can figure out yourself.

**EDIT** As Hlawu M suggested, to get the last part of the string, use the following code:

```
var lastString = window.location.pathname.split('/').reverse()[0]
```

Comment: Also, if you just want the last part of the URL string , i.e /string/string2/lastPart:

var lastString = window.location.pathname.split('/').reverse()[0];

should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion @HlawuM I appreciate it and added it to my answer.

Comment: no problem and thanks for using my snippet as part of your answer.